# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14

Tags: android, android-support-library, noclassdeffounderror, android-support-design

All of a sudden, when I try to compile my project,and run my app,  I start getting this runtime error-

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:93)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:77)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:429)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:57)
            at com.example.shubhamkanodia.bookmybook.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:70)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Here's what I've tried doing:

1) Excluding support-v4 from all my dependencies and manually specifying an older version, support     `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+'`.

What is interesting to note is that **MainActivity is not my launcher activity**. So the app works fine in the launcher activity.. But as soon as mainactivity opens, it fails.

My build.gradle is given below (i had to mess it up a little to fix another [another design library bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=175086), so don't mind the excludes )

```
     compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.5.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-v7'

    }
    compile('com.android.support:palette-v7:22.2.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-v7'

    }
    compile('com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:lib-core:3.1.0@aar') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-v7'

    }
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile ("org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion")
            {
                exclude module: 'support-v4'
                exclude module: 'support-v7'

            }
    compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-v7'

    }
    compile('com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-v7'

    }
    compile('com.android.support:design:22.2.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-v7'

    }
    compile project(':cognalys')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'ParseCrashReporting-*.jar')
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.5.0'){
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-v7'

    }
    compile ('com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-v7'

    }
    compile('com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-v7'

    }
    compile('com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.5.1') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-v7'

    }
    compile ('me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:1.7.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-v7'

    }
    compile('com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.0.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-v7'

    }
    compile ('com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'){
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-v7'

    }
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+'
    compile ('jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:1.0.3@aar'){
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-v7'

    }
    compile ('jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage:gpuimage-library:1.2.3@aar'){
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-v7'

    }
    compile ('com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-v7'

    }
    compile('com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-v7'

    }
```

Comment: You must have duplicated and/or conflicting support libraries (versions).

Comment: @shkschneider I have already tried excluding v4 and v7 from all my dependencies (check above)

Comment: Getting this error after I updated Android Studio..still not able to resolve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From all the exclusions you exposed, I have to say that what I read is that you just banned `support-v4` and `support-v7` from your application (even from `design` and `appcompat`).

So try to keep them at the end ^^

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0' // no exclusion
```

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:support-v7:22.2.0' is not a valid dependency ( or v7-21.+) for that matter... It keeps saying support library not found - check SDK Manager, even thought I have latest versions intalled

Comment: Sorry, edited. Include `AppCompat` without exclusion. This way you'll get `support-v4` only from `AppCompat` and only once, because you excluded it everywhere else ^^

Comment: I cannot use support v4 that comes along with appcomvat-7:22.2, because that will provide me with support v4:22.2. I can only use support v4:21.1.1, hence the excludes. ( https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=175086)

Comment: If you need to use `support-v4:21.1.1`, why do you include other libraries at version 22.2.0? This shall make conflicts. Have you tried change `appcompat-v7` and others to 21.1.1?

Comment: this helped me : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27698287/noclassdeffounderror-with-android-studio-on-android-4

Comment: @user1570693 seems unrelated, you are reffering to MultiDex, which solves the "above 65K methods" limit

Comment: As I said. I had the exact same error and search for days until I made this change. I was using multidex to avoid the 65K limit but forgot to Include compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0 and call MultiDex.install() in my Application. So it was working fine only with recent phones.

Answer (score 1):

for me the solution has been adding

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

to the manifest

Answer (score 0):

just enable the multidex. That worked for me. follow the link please https://stackoverflow.com/a/31724383/3040893