# Getting exception : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport, appcompatactivity

I updated Android Studio and the android design library recently since then I am getting an exception `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14`.

Not sure what is the problem, I tried almost everything, its working in lollipop 5.1 device(nexus 4) but it does not work in Android 4.4 device and 4.02 device. It was working before the updation in all versions.

**I tried all solutions mentioned in stackoverflow but nothing worked for me.**

Also tried removing the line `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'` in build.gradle but it did not work too.

Also tried cleaning and rebuilding and again it did not work.

```
07-13 18:51:26.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1105): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-13 18:51:26.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1105): Process: com.stackoverflow.ranjith.androidprojdel, PID: 1105
07-13 18:51:26.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1105): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14
07-13 18:51:26.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:93)
07-13 18:51:26.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:77)
07-13 18:51:26.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:429)
07-13 18:51:26.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:57)
07-13 18:51:26.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at com.stackoverflow.ranjith.androidprojdel.AppCompActivity.onCreate(AppCompActivity.java:34)
07-13 18:51:26.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
07-13 18:51:26.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-13 18:51:26.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
07-13 18:51:26.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
07-13 18:51:26.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-13 18:51:26.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
07-13 18:51:26.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-13 18:51:26.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-13 18:51:26.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
07-13 18:51:26.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-13 18:51:26.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-13 18:51:26.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-13 18:51:26.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-13 18:51:26.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.stackoverflow.ranjith.androidprojdel"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
repositories {
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.flavienlaurent.datetimepicker:library:0.0.2'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.8'
    compile 'com.github.ranjithnair02:simplecontactmview:0.6-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.github.alamkanak:android-week-view:1.2.3'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.4.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.digits.sdk.android:digits:1.6.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

**My style.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#673AB7</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#512DA8</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#4400b0</item>
    </style>
<resources>
```

Comment: update.... ia have this issue too,  but i work in 2 project: first worked nice, second included compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0' and this error

Comment: I tried that too and it did not work...I have mentioned it in the question too

Comment: Ya I use theme parent as `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`...I just added the style.xml in the question too..

Comment: yeaah !!!  i replace >> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0' to compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+')  , and removed  "multiDexEnabled true"  it solved my problem )

Comment: this helped me :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27698287/noclassdeffounderror-with-android-studio-on-android-4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I resolved this issue and if anyone is experiencing this issue try these options(3rd point fixed my problem):

1. Add `multiDexEnabled true` in defaultConfig of build.gradle.

   `defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.something.ranjith.androidprojdel"
       minSdkVersion 15
       targetSdkVersion 22
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
       multiDexEnabled true
   }`
2. Remove android support library if your activity extends `AppcompatActivity'

   `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.+'`  //remove this
3. If you have `PlayServices` in your app then remove the `PlayServices` and add the individual APIs.
   **For eg:-** if you are using `PlayServices` for ads then just add `compile com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0` instead of `compile com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0`

### **List of individual APIs of PlayServices:**

- **Google+**  `com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.5.0`
- **Google Account Login** `com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.5.0`
- **Google Actions, Base Client Library**  `com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.5.0`
- **Google App Indexing**  `com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:7.5.0`
- **Google App Invites**   `com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:7.5.0`
- **Google Analytics** 
  `com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.5.0`
- **Google Cast**  `com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:7.5.0`
- **Google Cloud Messaging**   `com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0`
- **Google Drive** `com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:7.5.0`
- **Google Fit**   `com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:7.5.0`
- **Google Location, Activity Recognition, and Places**
  `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0`
- **Google Maps**  `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0`
- **Mobile Ads**   `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0`
- **Google Nearby**    `com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:7.5.0`
- **Google Panorama Viewer** `com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:7.5.0
- **Google Play Game services** `com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:7.5.0`
- **SafetyNet** `com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:7.5.0`
- **Google Wallet**    `com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:7.5.0`
- **Android Wear**  `com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:7.5.0`