# Getting Nullpointer exception after updating to Android design support 22.2.1

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, androiddesignsupport, android-appcompat

My project was working fine just before I updated to Android design support 22.2.1, after I update and run the program I get the below error. **The exception does not tell which line in code or the java file is causing the error so don't know what code to post**.It seems some internal error of android design support.

My activity is extending `AppCompatActivity` and my test device API 15(Android 4.04).

I am using `NavigationView` and `DrawerLayout` in my code.

My **build.gradle**

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.stackoverflow.ranjith.androidprojdel"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.+'
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.+'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.8.1'
}
```

**Exception:**

```
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView.setIcon(NavigationMenuItemView.java:113)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView.initialize(NavigationMenuItemView.java:72)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.getView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:305)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:220)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2045)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1772)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:732)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1625)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1875)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:444)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:931)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:444)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1653)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1511)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1416)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:444)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1653)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1511)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1416)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:444)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1490)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2455)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
07-19 00:52:49.338: E/AndroidRuntime(15556):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Update**

When I rollback to 22.2.0 the error disappears, not sure what is the problem.

Comment: 22.2.1 update has been released?

Comment: @Eenvincible yes, yesterday: https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/XTtNCPviwpj

Comment: Yes..along with it new issues too. Last week I faced different problem when I updated to new library and now I have new problems.

Comment: Last update had this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31384935/getting-exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v7-app-appco/31432568#31432568

Comment: Set icon probably null holder navigation menu item view class  line 113

Comment: Didn't understand what you are trying to say..

Comment: Never roll back, fix the problem. Where is your code?

Comment: @JaredBurrows I had to because for the last update I got an exception and I wasted 2 days trying to fix the issue. This was the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31384935/getting-exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v7-app-appco/31432568#31432568

Comment: That issue has nothing to do this issue. You simply added multidex.

Comment: Thats right. I was just saying the code was working before the update and later after the update it stopped working, just like the issue in this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is related to the NavigationView menu xml.

Mine looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_subheader"
            android:title="Titulo">
        <menu>
            <item
                    android:id="@+id/navigation_sub_item_1"
                    android:icon="@drawable/abc_btn_radio_material"
                    android:title="sub-1"/>
            <item
                    android:id="@+id/navigation_sub_item_2"
                    android:icon="@drawable/abc_btn_rating_star_on_mtrl_alpha"
                    android:title="sub-2"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

but if I switch to a project drawable icon, its fixed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_subheader"
            android:title="Titulo">
        <menu>
            <item
                    android:id="@+id/navigation_sub_item_1"
              ----> android:icon="@drawable/some_local_drawable"
                    android:title="sub-1"/>
            <item
                    android:id="@+id/navigation_sub_item_2"
              ----> android:icon="@drawable/some_local_drawable"
                    android:title="sub-2"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Of course, this happens after updating to 22.2.1

Comment: Let me try it out. +1 for the answer.

Comment: This is working..Thanks. Will wait for the next update and the issues that come with that update :)

Comment: You should never use the `abc_` icons. Always supply your own, those are apart of the library.

Comment: Now I got to know that. :)

Comment: @Jared, In my case the Android Studio template auto generated those references.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was able to avoid it with this code:

```
View header = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.nav_header_main, null);
navigationView.addHeaderView(header);
TextView text = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.textView);
texto.setText("HELLO");
```