# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14 upon updating to appcompat v23 - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I'm trying to update all my support libraries and I'm getting the no class definition found exception and I can't figure out why.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:135)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:117)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:456)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:59)
```

Here are my dependencies.

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'
compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')
compile files('libs/json-simple-1.1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/jsoup-1.7.2.jar')
compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
compile files('libs/richnotification-v1.0.0.jar')
compile files('libs/sdk-v1.0.0.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

And my config.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 23

    multiDexEnabled true
}

configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}

useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Here are the things I've tried out so far.

- Use a custom application class that extends `MultiDexApplication`
- Use `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'` instead of the other two declarations.
- Use the latest/earlier verions of gradle
- Everything mentioned in [Getting exception : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31384935/getting-exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v7-app-appco)

None of these seem to make any difference. What exactly am i doing wrong ?

---

**EDIT: Fixed my issue. I had to remove support v-13 from my libs folder and the gradle build line and include all the support v-4 modules and then it worked fine.**

Comment: Remove compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar') and use com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.0