# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: rx.subjects.PublishSubject

Tags: java, android, adobecreativesdk

I've added Adobe creative SDK into my project and now im getting an error when im trying to move to Edit image function.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: rx.subjects.PublishSubject
                at com.adobe.creativesdk.aviary.internal.account.AdobeAccountConnection.<init>(AdobeAccountConnection.java:45)
                at com.adobe.creativesdk.aviary.AdobeImageEditorActivity.onCreate(AdobeImageEditorActivity.java:517)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5268)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2178)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2264)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:144)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1259)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5136)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:740)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I went through the documentations but i've no idea why im getting this error

i have attached my code

```
    package com.sliit.dailyselfie.Camera;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.IdRes;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.adobe.creativesdk.aviary.AdobeImageIntent;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar;
import com.roughike.bottombar.OnMenuTabClickListener;
import com.sliit.dailyselfie.R;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import rebus.bottomdialog.BottomDialog;


public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int ActivityStartCAM=0;
    private final static int EDIT_IMAGE=1;
    private ImageView IV;
    private String ImageFileLoaction="";

    BottomBar CamBottomBar;
    ImageButton bcan,bsnap,bdesc;
    Dialog d;
    BottomDialog dialog;
    String challenge;
    Bundle extras;
    boolean picpresent=false;

    Uri ImageUri;






    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        IV = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.snap1);

        IV.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {


                if (picpresent) {
                    dialog = new BottomDialog(CameraActivity.this);
                    dialog.title("Options");
                    dialog.canceledOnTouchOutside(true);
                    dialog.cancelable(true);
                    dialog.inflateMenu(R.menu.camera_bottomsheet_menu);
                    dialog.setOnItemSelectedListener(new BottomDialog.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onItemSelected(int id) {
                            switch (id) {
                                case R.id.addeffects:
                                    image();
                                    return true;

                                case R.id.crop:
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"crop",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    return true;

                                default:
                                    return false;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    dialog.show();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });


         extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            challenge = extras.getString("Challenge");
        }


        CamBottomBar = BottomBar.attach(this, savedInstanceState);
        CamBottomBar.noNavBarGoodness();



        CamBottomBar.setItemsFromMenu(R.menu.camera_bottombar, new OnMenuTabClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMenuTabSelected(@IdRes int menuItemId) {

                if (menuItemId == R.id.nav_back) {

                    IV.setImageResource(R.drawable.selfieimage);
                    IV.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
                    picpresent = false;

                } else if (menuItemId == R.id.nav_takeSnap) {
                    Intent CAMint= new Intent();
                    CAMint.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    File photoFile=null;
                    try{
                        photoFile=createImageFile();
                    }catch(IOException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    CAMint.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    startActivityForResult(CAMint, ActivityStartCAM);


                } else if (menuItemId == R.id.nav_addDetails) {
                    if (picpresent) {

                        switch (challenge) {

                            case "fitness":
                                d = new Dialog(CameraActivity.this);
                                d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                                d.setContentView(R.layout.fitnessdialog);
                                ImageView fitim = (ImageView) d.findViewById(R.id.fitdialogimg);
                                TextView fittxt = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.fitdialogdesc);
                                d.show();
                                break;

                            case "maternity":
                                d = new Dialog(CameraActivity.this);
                                d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                                d.setContentView(R.layout.maternitydialog);
                                ImageView matimg = (ImageView) d.findViewById(R.id.matdialogimg);
                                TextView mattxt = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.matdialogdesc);
                                d.show();

                                break;

                            case "child":
                                d = new Dialog(CameraActivity.this);
                                d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                                d.setContentView(R.layout.childdialog);
                                ImageView chilimg = (ImageView) d.findViewById(R.id.childialogimg);
                                TextView chiltxt = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.childialogdesc);
                                d.show();

                                break;

                        }


                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, "Please select image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
//
//                CamBottomBar.mapColorForTab(0, ContextCompat.getColor(CameraActivity.this, R.color.bottomPrimary));
//                CamBottomBar.mapColorForTab(1, ContextCompat.getColor(CameraActivity.this, R.color.bottomPrimary));
//                CamBottomBar.mapColorForTab(2, ContextCompat.getColor(CameraActivity.this, R.color.bottomPrimary));


            }

            @Override
            public void onMenuTabReSelected(@IdRes int menuItemId) {


                if (menuItemId == R.id.nav_back) {

                    IV.setImageResource(R.drawable.selfieimage);
                    IV.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
                    picpresent = false;


                } else if (menuItemId == R.id.nav_takeSnap) {
                    Intent CAMint = new Intent();
                    CAMint.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try {
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    CAMint.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    startActivityForResult(CAMint, ActivityStartCAM);


                } else if (menuItemId == R.id.nav_addDetails) {

                    if (picpresent) {

                        switch (challenge) {

                            case "fitness":
                                d = new Dialog(CameraActivity.this);
                                d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                                d.setContentView(R.layout.fitnessdialog);
                                ImageView fitim = (ImageView) d.findViewById(R.id.fitdialogimg);
                                TextView fittxt = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.fitdialogdesc);
                                d.show();
                                break;

                            case "maternity":
                                d = new Dialog(CameraActivity.this);
                                d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                                d.setContentView(R.layout.maternitydialog);
                                ImageView matimg = (ImageView) d.findViewById(R.id.matdialogimg);
                                TextView mattxt = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.matdialogdesc);
                                d.show();

                                break;

                            case "child":
                                d = new Dialog(CameraActivity.this);
                                d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                                d.setContentView(R.layout.childdialog);
                                ImageView chilimg = (ImageView) d.findViewById(R.id.childialogimg);
                                TextView chiltxt = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.childialogdesc);
                                d.show();

                                break;

                        }


                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, "Please select image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }

//
//                CamBottomBar.mapColorForTab(0, ContextCompat.getColor(CameraActivity.this, R.color.bottomPrimary));
//                CamBottomBar.mapColorForTab(1, ContextCompat.getColor(CameraActivity.this, R.color.bottomPrimary));
//                CamBottomBar.mapColorForTab(2, ContextCompat.getColor(CameraActivity.this, R.color.bottomPrimary));


            }
        });



    }


    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        rotateImage(setReducedImageSize());
        IV.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        if(!picpresent){
            IV.setImageResource(R.drawable.selfieimage);
            IV.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        }
    }

    public void TakePhoto(View v){
        Intent CAMint= new Intent();
        CAMint.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File photoFile=null;
        try{
            photoFile=createImageFile();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        CAMint.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
        startActivityForResult(CAMint, ActivityStartCAM);

    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode==ActivityStartCAM  && resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            rotateImage(setReducedImageSize());
           ImageUri = Uri.parse(ImageFileLoaction);
            IV.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            picpresent=true;

        }
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode==EDIT_IMAGE) {


                /* Make a case for the request code we passed to startActivityForResult() */

                    /* Show the image! */
            Uri editedImageUri = data.getData();
            ImageUri=data.getData();
           Glide.with(this).load(editedImageUri).into(IV);
            picpresent=true;



        }

    }

    File createImageFile()throws IOException{
        String timestamp= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFieldname="IMAGE "+timestamp+"_";
        File storageDeirectory= Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image=File.createTempFile(imageFieldname,".jpg",storageDeirectory);
        ImageFileLoaction=image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }

    private Bitmap  setReducedImageSize(){
        int taretimagevieweidth=IV.getWidth();
        int targetimageviewheight=IV.getHeight();
        BitmapFactory.Options bmfop= new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmfop.inJustDecodeBounds=true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ImageFileLoaction,bmfop);
        int Cameraheight=bmfop.outHeight;
        int Camerawidth=bmfop.outWidth;
        int scalefactor =Math.min(Camerawidth/taretimagevieweidth,Cameraheight/targetimageviewheight);
        bmfop.inSampleSize=scalefactor;
        bmfop.inJustDecodeBounds=false;
        return  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ImageFileLoaction,bmfop);
    }

    private void rotateImage(Bitmap bitmap){
        ExifInterface exifInterface = null;
        try{
            exifInterface = new ExifInterface(ImageFileLoaction);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int orientation = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        switch (orientation){
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                matrix.setRotate(90);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                matrix.postRotate(180);
                break;
            default:

        }
        Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        IV.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);
    }


    public void image(){
      /* 1) Make a new Uri object (Replace this with a real image on your device) */
        Uri imageUri = ImageUri;

        /* 2) Create a new Intent */
        Intent imageEditorIntent = new AdobeImageIntent.Builder(this)
                .setData(imageUri)
                .build();

        /* 3) Start the Image Editor with request code 1 */
        startActivityForResult(imageEditorIntent,EDIT_IMAGE);

    }

}
```

Comment: try this gradle dependencies , dependencies {
    compile 'com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-android:0.20.7'
}

Answer (score 4):

This is because you are using a version of Android 4.x, and the MultiDex is not correctly implemented. I solved this problem following the next steps:

1. Add the following lines in **module.gradle**

   `defaultConfig { multiDexEnabled true }`
   `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'`
2. Extend the class application from **MultiDexApplication**

Example:

```
public class Globalapplication extends MultiDexApplication implements IAviaryClientCredentials {...}
```

3. override `attachBaseContext` in the previous class

Example:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    MultiDex.install(this);
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
}
```

for more information read: 
[NoClassDefFoundError with Android Studio on Android 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27698287/noclassdeffounderror-with-android-studio-on-android-4#)
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Answer (score 0):

According to Oracle documentation,
*Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no definition of the class could be found.
The searched-for class definition existed when the currently executing class was compiled, but the definition can no longer be found.*

So, Definition of `rx.subjects.PublishSubject` is not found...

Comment: You have to post your code for better understanding

Comment: ive attache the code there is a function in below called image() where i call the edit activity

Comment: @Tharaka..The produced error is all because of the library you are using...just ensure that you have attach all necessary libraries along with your project by ensuring their compatible API level.....

Comment: @Tharaka try this gradle dependencies , dependencies {
    compile 'com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-android:0.20.7'
}

Answer (score 0):

look at the packages it seems somehow you are not able to access the rx.subjects.PublishSubject package or is missing. make sure you are importing  rx.subjects.*;

Comment: try this gradle dependencies , dependencies {
    compile 'com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-android:0.20.7'
}

Comment: @ExceptionLover now im getting an error like this   
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: rx/Observable$6.class

Comment: i meant like
import rx.subjects.*;