# app in virtual device crashes but on actual device works fine

Tags: java, android, android-virtual-device

My android app is crashing in AVD (android virtual device) but on actual device it is working fine. The android major version on both device is same.

Is it possible that virtual device is not allocating the enough memory to app while as actual device is allocating memory, the reason i'm suspecting this is because when app crashes on virtual device shows error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Comment: Yes.                                                                 (so, what's your AVD settings, if you would copy/paste the CatLog output, from AVD, it would be visible how big memory chunk allocation failed, etc... some details would be needed for any chance to receive more detailed answer).

Comment: Thanks @Ped7g I managed to figured out the issue using this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27698287/noclassdeffounderror-with-android-studio-on-android-4