# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError $$inlined$forEach$lambda$1 in Kotlin

Tags: android, lambda, kotlin

I am currently working on an Android application with Kotlin in version 1.1.1

In my code, I have imbrication of several `forEach` structures in order to read several `MutableList` and `MutableMap`.

Unfortunately, my app crashes with the following stacktrace :

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com.package.fragment.ReminderAddFragment$onRetrieveBusinessObjects$$inlined$forEach$lambda$1
>   at
>   com.package.fragment.ReminderAddFragment.onRetrieveBusinessObjects(ReminderAddFragment.kt:275)
>   at
>   com.smartnsoft.droid4me.app.Droid4mizer.onRetrieveBusinessObjects(Droid4mizer.java:552)
>   at
>   com.smartnsoft.droid4me.app.Droid4mizer.onRetrieveBusinessObjectsInternal(Droid4mizer.java:606)
>   at
>   com.smartnsoft.droid4me.app.Droid4mizer.access$000(Droid4mizer.java:46)
>   at com.smartnsoft.droid4me.app.Droid4mizer$1.run(Droid4mizer.java:197)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Here the code

```
tutorialCategories.forEach { (_, _, _, _, _, tutorials) ->
  tutorials.forEach { tutorial ->
    if (tutorial.id == simpleReminderFromExtra.tutorialId)
    {
      //...
      val mapOfreminders = mutableMapOf<Int, MutableList<Reminder>>()
      val reminders = ReminderServices.getReminderByTutorialId(simpleReminderFromExtra.tutorialId)

      reminders.forEach { reminder ->
        //...
      }

      mapOfreminders.forEach { _, finalReminders ->
        //...

        finalReminders.forEach { reminder ->
          //...
        }

        //...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Where :

- `tutorialCategories` is a `List` ;
- `tutorials` is a `List` ;
- `reminders` is a `List` ;

The line 275 of the code is `mapOfreminders.forEach { _, finalReminders ->`.

In the debugger, I can evaluate the `mapOfreminders` variable and everything seems to be alright.

If someone can help to resolve this issue !

Comment: Could you also specify, what version of Kotlin do you use?

Comment: I am using Kotlin 1.1.1. I have edited my post.

Comment: Can you post more context, like your includes and variable definitions? Can you, somehow fetch the version in code before the crash? If you are getting a no class-def error, you are either distributing your binary without the required dependencies, or are running with a different version then you built with.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

After reading Dan Lew's [post](http://blog.danlew.net/2017/03/16/kotlin-puzzler-whose-line-is-it-anyways/) a couple days ago, I'll make a suggestion that this can be caused by using `Map.forEach { k, v -> }` method from Java 8, which may be unavailable in Android runtime.

You could try to use another [forEach](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each.html) with the single entry parameter that comes from the Kotlin standard library:

```
mapOfreminders.forEach { (_, finalReminders) -> }
```

Here the *parentheses* are used to destructure entry parameter into two variables: ignored key and `finalReminders` value.

Comment: also, you need to disable instant run!

Comment: does anybody knows of a compiler flag that would throw an error or at least a warning when using the BiConsumer function from Java 8 instead of the Kotlin one? It adds crashes in my app and I'd like to make sure that I never use the wrong version again

Comment: @dvkch That `forEach` function from Java 8 should be caught by linter in Android Studio starting from 3.2. See this issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80464232

Comment: @ilya it is indeed underlined in red but doesn't prevent compilation in 3.2 RC3. that's a start, probably have to enable something somewhere. thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 13):

I encountered this problem`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` on Android 6.0 and 6.0.1 by using

```
Map.forEach {key ,value -> }
```

this call java 8 api.

And then, I solved this problem by adding brackets to parameter:

```
Map.forEach {(key ,value) -> }
```

this call kotlin api

Answer (score 2):

Seems like this particular error doesn't happen on all phones. I faced a similar issue with Samsung Galaxy S7, where the app was crashing with ClassNotFoundError. This solution works if we still want to use lambda. 
Else replacing the lambda with `for ((key, value) in map) { ... }`also works.