# IOException: Failed to find byte code when upgrade to Android Studio 3.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.1

Yesterday, Google announced that Android Studio 3.1 is available in the stable release channel. So I give it a try.

Before of that my project was build successfully but after I upgraded AS to 3.1 and Gradle build tool to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0` (it forced upgrade gradle wrapper to 4.4), it failed with this given exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed to find byte code for android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager$TorchCallback
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:212)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor309.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed to find byte code for android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager$TorchCallback
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunTransform.doTransform(InstantRunTransform.java:312)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunTransform.transform(InstantRunTransform.java:178)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:221)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:217)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    ... 47 more
```

I'm already do a full clean rebuild or even **File**-> **Invalidate Caches/Restart..**, but it's still not working.

Anyone know how to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Try disabling instant run. It might just work!

Comment: I had the same problem and did what you went through - clean, invalidate, restart to to avail.  Fortunately, the suggestion by @AhmedHegazy - disabling instant run works for me.  I still hope to find a solution without disabling instant-run.

Comment: @Hong thank you, but instant run is very important to me :(

Comment: Concur.  This is why I hope for a solution without disabling it.  Hope Google will fix the bug ASAP.

Comment: Disabling instant run works just fine, but of course if you need it is better to revert it as other people mentioned... Bear in mind if you are looking to compile the app you can still do it via gradle, the exception you are getting is just an intant run thing.

Comment: This issue has been fixed in 3.3.0

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There is [an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72811718), which they promise to fix in 3.2. Until then you probably have to roll back to Android Studio 3.0 if you don't want to turn off instant run. Why they don't want to release a hotfix for this, I don't know. Seems to be a pretty important bug.

See:

[image]

I suggest voting for the issue, maybe this will motivate them to release the fix sooner.

Comment: Thank you! Hope they will release the fix soon.

Comment: This isssue was already fixed in Android Studio 3.2 Canary 10 - https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2018/04/android-studio-32-canary-10-now.html. Update on canary channel or wait for a stable 3.2 release ;)

Comment: See how to `disable Instant Run` here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46999669/how-to-disable-instant-run-for-android-studio-3-0/46999705

Comment: I've never had the chance to try this instant run, because for some weird reason it doesn't work when you have more than one process on the app. Maybe it already changed, but I should try again, but I will have to wait since this bug.

Comment: Today was the release of android studio 3.2 and I think they did not fix it? Has anyone had a similar experience?

Comment: Android Studio 3.2 brought up some other small problems for me but solved this one - deploying the app now with instantrun

Comment: After update Android Studio 3.2 still, face this issue Failed to find byte code for android/service/autofill/AutofillService

Answer (score 24):

Just as @Malcolm said, this is an Android Studio 3.1 issue.

If you don't want to revert Android Studio 3.1 to 3.0, you can **disable Instant Run.**

If you don't want to revert Android Studio 3.1 to 3.0, and do need Instant Run, you can edit **build.gradle** and **gradle-wrapper.properties** like below:

1. com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0

   ->  com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1
2. distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip

   ->  distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip

Comment: thanks you, Google already release AS 3.1.1 in stable channel which seem to fix this problem. But cause another problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49770112/execution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithandroidgradleclassshrinkerfo

Answer (score 11):

Disabling Instant Run worked for me

Comment: It sure does work, but it's barely an answer to question: why can't I use instant run?

Answer (score 3):

if you get unexpected/weird/stupid errors like this it's most probably because of

> Instant run

disable it and try again

Answer (score 1):

Firstly go to build menu and clean project. After cleaning rebuild the project.

If doesn't work then, Try to add this line in build gradle file:

```
 defaultConfig {
       multiDexEnabled true  
   }
```

For dependency:

```
dependencies 
    {
       compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    }
```

Comment: Thank you but it's not working, btw my project is only a small demo and absolutely do not need multidex.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, after disabling instant run.. The app was crashing at runtime and threw a `noClassDefFound` error.. In my case I was using the `forEach` lambda function of Java 8 on **Hashmap** instead of kotlin one..

A post [here](http://blog.danlew.net/2017/03/16/kotlin-puzzler-whose-line-is-it-anyways/) and similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42869086/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-inlinedforeachlambda1-in-kotlin) describes this.
You have to use parentheses around the key and value. eg:

```
dataSet.forEach { (header, dataList) ->    }
```

This will ensure to use the kotlin function.

Answer (score 0):

You ned to try clean and rebuild the project. If the problem still persist, remove the `.gradle` folder inside your project. Last, if none works, Use `File-> Invalidate Caches/Restart..` from Android Studio menu.

Answer (score 0):

As @Malcolm said, the issue is related to Android Studio 3.1.

It is still happening on Android Studio 3.1.2 if I try to run on a device with Android 5.1 while Instant Run enabled.

Invalidating caches, clearing / rebuilding project didn't work for me.

The issue was solved when I've switched to a device with Android 7.0 but I think Android 6.0+ would also work. If you are able to switch the device, give it a try. No need to disable Instant Run.

Comment: The same thing is happening to me on Android 6.0. Upwards from Nougat it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade the gradle build tool from `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1` to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1` works for me.