# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithAndroidGradleClassShrinkerForDebug' in Android Studio 3.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.1

I've just upgraded from Android Studio `3.1` to Android Studio `3.1.1` (but still using Gradle build tool `3.0.0`). When I run my app it causes this error:

```
:app:transformClassesWithAndroidGradleClassShrinkerForDebug
com/android/tools/profiler/agent/okhttp/OkHttp3Interceptor references unknown class: okhttp3/Interceptor
com/android/tools/profiler/agent/okhttp/OkHttp2Interceptor references unknown class: com/squareup/okhttp/Interceptor
com/android/tools/profiler/agent/okhttp/OkHttp3Interceptor references unknown class: okhttp3/Request
com/android/tools/profiler/agent/okhttp/OkHttp2Interceptor references unknown class: okio/Okio
com/android/tools/profiler/agent/okhttp/OkHttp3Interceptor references unknown class: okhttp3/ResponseBody
com/android/tools/profiler/agent/okhttp/OkHttp3Interceptor references unknown class: okio/Okio
com/android/tools/profiler/agent/okhttp/OkHttp2Interceptor references unknown class: com/squareup/okhttp/Request
com/android/tools/profiler/agent/okhttp/OkHttp3Interceptor references unknown class: okhttp3/Response
com/android/tools/profiler/agent/okhttp/OkHttp2Interceptor references unknown class: com/squareup/okhttp/Headers
com/android/tools/profiler/agent/okhttp/OkHttp2Interceptor references unknown class: com/squareup/okhttp/ResponseBody
com/android/tools/profiler/agent/okhttp/OkHttp2Interceptor references unknown class: com/squareup/okhttp/Interceptor$Chain
com/android/tools/profiler/agent/okhttp/OkHttp2Interceptor references unknown class: com/squareup/okhttp/Response$Builder
com/android/tools/profiler/agent/okhttp/OkHttp2Interceptor references unknown class: com/squareup/okhttp/Response
com/android/tools/profiler/agent/okhttp/OkHttp3Interceptor references unknown class: okhttp3/Headers
com/android/tools/profiler/agent/okhttp/OkHttp2Interceptor references unknown class: com/squareup/okhttp/RequestBody
com/android/tools/profiler/agent/okhttp/OkHttp3Interceptor references unknown class: okhttp3/OkHttpClient$Builder
com/android/tools/profiler/agent/okhttp/OkHttp3Interceptor references unknown class: okhttp3/HttpUrl
com/android/tools/profiler/agent/okhttp/OkHttp2Interceptor references unknown class: com/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient
com/android/tools/profiler/agent/okhttp/OkHttp2Interceptor references unknown class: okio/BufferedSource
com/android/tools/profiler/agent/okhttp/OkHttp3Interceptor references unknown class: okhttp3/Interceptor$Chain
com/android/tools/profiler/agent/okhttp/OkHttp3Interceptor references unknown class: okhttp3/Response$Builder
com/android/tools/profiler/agent/okhttp/OkHttp3Interceptor references unknown class: okhttp3/RequestBody
com/android/tools/profiler/agent/okhttp/OkHttp2Interceptor references unknown class: okio/BufferedSink
com/android/tools/profiler/agent/okhttp/OkHttp3Interceptor references unknown class: okio/BufferedSource
com/android/tools/profiler/agent/okhttp/OkHttp3Interceptor references unknown class: okio/BufferedSink
:app:transformClassesWithAndroidGradleClassShrinkerForDebug FAILED
:app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithAndroidGradleClassShrinkerForDebug'.
> Warnings found during shrinking, please use -dontwarn or -ignorewarnings to suppress them.
```

But I'm NOT using `okhttp` or any Http library (like Retrofit,..) in my project.

This error also happens when I'm upgrading Gradle build tool to the newest version `3.1.1`. I don't know why, everything is fine when I downgrade back to Android Studio `3.1.0`.

**app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.z.a.zcamera"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation project(path: ':libzcamera')
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
}
```

**Update:**

I think it is caused by Android Profiler tool's new feature: **the network profiler** because of the `com/android/tools/profiler/agent` path and I'm turning ON the advanced profiling to track network payload.

I also don't want to disable Proguard too.

Any ideas? Please help me.

Comment: paste here build.gradle on project level and app level so we can rectify for same @nhoxbypass

Comment: @ChiragTalsaniya I've updated the question

Comment: add build.gradle of **project(path: ':libzcamera')** this @nboxbypass

Comment: @ChiragTalsaniya nothing in there, I'm only compile support library.

Comment: change gradle as given in answer @nhoxbypass

Comment: is there any library inside your `libs`?

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך No, I'm only use some jniLibs

Comment: it's useless to shrink debug builds and this also prevents tests.

Comment: @MartinZeitler it's not useless bro, we have our own usecase for this. And how can shrink debug builds affect tests?

Comment: @nhoxbypass simply because the test app knows nothing about the obfuscation mapping; just alike this injected classes from the profiler are unknown. this use case is not supported by the framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like a bug of Android Studio 3.1.1. It's Android Profiler injects some additional code that is not well-handled by ProGuard. 
Building APKs or executing gradle commands manually is not affected.

**Option 1: *(prefered)*** Disable [advanced profiling](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler.html).

Option 2: Disable shrinking for Debug builds

Option 3: Include okhttp library while deploying app from Android Studio. [probably only for debug flavor] *(may be useful if measuring something, ProGuard will remove any unused methods, will be no big overhead)*

---

If solutions/quickfixes above don't work, please make sure you are not using okhttp. Maybe you are - and it's [not properly configured](https://github.com/square/okhttp#proguard). You may use `gradle app:dependencies` to check if okhttp is referenced in your project or any linked libraries.

Comment: Disabling advanced profiling works for me with Android Studio 3.1.4

Answer (score 0):

if  you are using 3.1.1

```
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
```

then your 
**app/build.gradle** should be like given below

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application' 
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.z.a.zcamera"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation project(path: ':libzcamera')
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
}
```

if **buildToolsVersion** require then use this

```
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
```

also change gradle in **project(path: ':libzcamera')**

Comment: So gradle build tool 3.1.1 need target SDK is 27? I changed but it's not working!

Comment: @nhoxbypass once try with   **minifyEnabled false**