# Android Studio 3.1 Build Fails with ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew, android-gradle-3.1.0

I am experiencing this error when building my project after Android Studio (AS) update to version 3.1:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':MyModule:transformClassesWithProfilers-transformForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
...
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: package.mymodule.MyClass
```

But actually the class package.mymodule.MyClass is available.
Also it was building in AS v3.0.1, before the update to AS v3.1.

It happens only when building in Android Studio. When building the project from console with

```
>gradlew assembleDebug
```

it builds without error.
I have also tried to use former gradle version 4.1 (instead of 4.4) in gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

and former AS gradle plugin version 3.0.1 (instead of 3.1.0) in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
}
```

without success. I am still getting the same error when building in AS v3.1.
I have also tried to disable Instant Run. It didn't help.

Here is the full stacktrace:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':MyModule:transformClassesWithProfilers-transformForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: package.mymodule.MyClass
    at com.android.tools.profiler.asm.ClassWriter.getCommonSuperClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.tools.profiler.asm.ClassWriter.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.tools.profiler.asm.Frame.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.tools.profiler.asm.Frame.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.tools.profiler.asm.MethodWriter.visitMaxs(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.tools.profiler.asm.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.tools.profiler.asm.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.tools.profiler.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.tools.profiler.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.tools.profiler.asm.ClassWriter.toByteArray(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.tools.profiler.ProfilerTransform.accept(ProfilerTransform.java:74)
    at com.android.tools.profiler.ProfilerTransform.accept(ProfilerTransform.java:39)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.CustomClassTransform.apply(CustomClassTransform.java:301)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.CustomClassTransform.transformFile(CustomClassTransform.java:288)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.CustomClassTransform.transform(CustomClassTransform.java:222)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:221)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:217)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:212)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor402.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 32 more
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the above issue with checking out another copy of the project from Git. Afterwards my project was building also with AS 3.1.

I have not figured out the exact reason. This is what I did:

1) Delete the project folder and cloned repository from Git again, using the same folder name as before > I got the same error as above again

2) Delete the project folder and cloned repository from Git again, using another  folder name > works ...?

Anyway, now I have the same issue with AS 3.1 as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49525708/ioexception-failed-to-find-byte-code-when-upgrade-to-android-studio-3-1). After disabling Instant Run the build then worked.