# Android NoClassDefFoundError on android 4.4.2

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

When I try to run my app on Android 4.4.2 it is giving me this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: my.package, PID: 24775
              java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: my/package/models/Transaction
                  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:610)
                  at com.activeandroid.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredColumnFields(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
                  at com.activeandroid.TableInfo.<init>(TableInfo.java:66)
                  at com.activeandroid.ModelInfo.loadModelFromMetaData(ModelInfo.java:101)
                  at com.activeandroid.ModelInfo.<init>(ModelInfo.java:61)
                  at com.activeandroid.Cache.initialize(Cache.java:66)
                  at com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid.initialize(ActiveAndroid.java:44)
                  at com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid.initialize(ActiveAndroid.java:34)
                  at com.activeandroid.content.ContentProvider.onCreate(ContentProvider.java:39)
                  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1591)
                  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1562)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5233)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4827)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4710)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:174)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1367)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
               Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "my.package.models.Transaction" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/my.package-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/my.package-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
```

However, for Android 5.0 and above it is working without any errors.

What is the reason and how can I fix it?

*Note: there is a similar question on StackOverflow but it does not have any answers.*

Comment: are you using proguard?

Comment: have you tried multiDexEnabled true in your build.gradle try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609734/how-to-enable-multidexing-with-the-new-android-multidex-support-library

Comment: @VinayRathod It was a project done by others and now I'm responsible to support it. I think proguard is used because in app's build.gradle file, there's " proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro' "

Comment: @Himanshuitmca yeah, I tried

Comment: Its happening due to proguard, just add -keep public class my/package/models/Transaction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the answer for this question here:

1. [NoClassDefFoundError with Android Studio on Android 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27698287/noclassdeffounderror-with-android-studio-on-android-4)
2. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Just go to disable Instant Run Go to

> File -> Settings -> Build,Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run ->
>   Uncheck the checkbox for instant run

Run your app once.