# Exception "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class..." on Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-4.3-jelly-bean

When I try to run my existing application (using Android Studio 3.1.3) on Android 4.4.2 it is not running and showing this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: my.project, PID: 9428
              java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: uz/uno/models/Transaction
                  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:610)
                  at com.activeandroid.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredColumnFields(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
                  at com.activeandroid.TableInfo.<init>(TableInfo.java:66)
                  at com.activeandroid.ModelInfo.loadModelFromMetaData(ModelInfo.java:101)
                  at com.activeandroid.ModelInfo.<init>(ModelInfo.java:61)
                  at com.activeandroid.Cache.initialize(Cache.java:66)
                  at com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid.initialize(ActiveAndroid.java:44)
                  at com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid.initialize(ActiveAndroid.java:34)
                  at com.activeandroid.content.ContentProvider.onCreate(ContentProvider.java:39)
                  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1591)
                  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1562)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5233)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4827)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4710)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:174)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1367)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
               Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "my.project.models.Transaction" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/my.project-5.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/my.project-5, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
```

Pay attention to the exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "my.project.models.Transaction" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/my.project-5.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/my.project-5, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

I found out that everytime when I try to run and it crashes the number in the exception increases `my.project-5`. (First time it was `my.project-1`, then `my.project-2`, and so on).

**What is the problem and how can I fix this error?**

*Note: This error is also occuring on android 4.3. However, for android 5.0 and above it is working well.*

**Edit: Answer**
After doing some research, I found the answer here:

1. [NoClassDefFoundError with Android Studio on Android 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27698287/noclassdeffounderror-with-android-studio-on-android-4)
2. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Comment: Did you try cleaning your project?

Comment: You looks like to be using Reflection, this wont prompt for warnings on AndroidStudio about version compatibility, check if the methods are supported on Android4.3

Comment: close your project delete your .idea folder and run again

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a conflict with some code that requires at least android 5.0 but you are running in 4.4.2.
See the documentation here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms and here: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility

**Post the code so we can help you better.**