# Android aar file Inside a Library module - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android

I am having an external library `(constants.aar)` file. I have kept this `.aar` file in to my Android library module project's `(sdk-module)/lib` folder. This `sdk-module` has classes which uses methods from `constants.aar`.

Compiling the `sdk-module` generates `sdk-module.aar` file.

In my application i am including this `sdk-module.aar` file. When i am trying to use certain class files of `sdk-module`, i am getting `NoClassDefFoundError`.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: "class file from constant.aar";
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "xyz" on path:

I have unzipped the `sdk-module.aar` file and i can see that `constants.aar` file is available in its `/lib` folder.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Try this by implementing MultiDex support -                                                                     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27698287/noclassdeffounderror-with-android-studio-on-android-4

Answer (score 0):

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ....
        multiDexEnabled true // Add this line in your build.gradle file
    }

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Extend : MultiDexApplication Class In in your ApplicationClass.java

```
public class BusinessCardApplication extends MultiDexApplication { ... }
```

**OR**

```
MultiDex.install(this); //add this line
```

Either, See this library's Issues File. If It Is from library's issue there is also define this error detail